# How to write http logs in android logs file

Tags: android, http, logging

How to write HTTP Logs in my Logs file for my app? I already searched a lot for this but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: You want to write logs into a file?

Comment: What library/technique are you using for your HTTP calls?

Comment: Any update? Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write logs to a file you can try this useful [library](https://github.com/JiongBull/jlog), called jlog. It allows you to write to a log file keeping android log levels (info, verbose, debug etc.). Obviously you can also log http responses.